# How can I run flapdoodle MongodStarter with --auth option

Tags: mongodb, testing

I recently configured my mongoDB to use --auth while starting the process.

Now I need to change the accessing Javacode and the tests. For the tests I am using flapdoodle tools like MongodStarter.

There are some example codes at http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=de.flapdoodle.embed.process.config.IRuntimeConfig

But I still need help to build the correct code to start the MongodStarter with the --auth option. 
For example I could do this

```
MongodStarter runtime = MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance();
    IMongoCmdOptions cmdOptions = new MongoCmdOptionsBuilder.MongoCmdOptions(null, null, true, false, false, false, false, true, true)
    def mongodConfig = new MongodConfigBuilder.ImmutableMongodConfig(Version.V3_0_4, new Net(27017, Network.localhostIsIPv6()),new Timeout(), cmdOptions, "CT.pid", new Storage(), false, null, new HashMap())
    mongodExe = runtime.prepare(mongodConfig);
    mongod = mongodExe.start();
    mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
```

But in the .MongoCmdOptions()-method there are a lot of parameters, which I don't care about and don't know suitable values. Only the 8th is the one, that I want to use. It is the --auth param. Filling the others with some values, I get exceptions.

A similar problem I have with MongodConfigBuilder.ImmutableMongodConfig(). I put some fantasy values to it, because there are a lot.

Can you give me a working example configuration I can test with? I crafted for some days now, but still didn't find a good combination of configuration types and values. I could imagine, that there is a simpler way, but I could not find an example.

Answer (score 1):

[This "embedded-services" library](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/embedded-services) has the authentication configuration built in for [flapdoodle's Embedded MongoDB](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo). The full working example you want is in [MongoEmbeddedService.java file](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/embedded-services/blob/embedded-services-1.21/src/main/java/ru/yandex/qatools/embed/service/MongoEmbeddedService.java) ([line 179](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/embedded-services/blob/embedded-services-1.21/src/main/java/ru/yandex/qatools/embed/service/MongoEmbeddedService.java#L179))

It's not a bad idea to use this tool instead of writing your own. Otherwise, make sure you create yourself an admin user.